# R Markdown Link Using Code Chunk

Tags: r, markdown, knitr

I have an Rmd file which interacts with a number of scripts and variables. In these scripts, there is a section where I want to provide a link. That link address is field in a data frame. What I am trying to do is something like the following:

```
[Click to Visit Report] (`r as.character(ModelAttributes[1,"ReportLink"])`)
```

However, the URL component of the markdown does not want to recognize the code chunk inside it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please include a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Specifically, what code are you you using and do you get a specific error? Also, checkout this [page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Have you tried without the typo: there should be no space between ] and ( ?

Comment: Yep, i think you just need to remove that space between `]` and `(`, just tried it, works for me

Comment: Silly mistake, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following code in the file `file.Rmd`

````
```{r}
df <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2), 
             url = c("http://google.com", "https://github.com"), 
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

[Click to Visit Report](`r df[1, "url"]`)
````

Here's the result (clicking the link works)

[image]